# C# Rest service and Salesforce

Tags: rest, c#

I am having issues with my Rest calls, I am not even sure I should be using Rest at this point.

But I currently have the following code in my Salesforce Development console and it call my C# Rest service as of now things are working, but I do not know how to read my incoming request on the C# side, which I need to do so I can insert the data into a sql server table.

```
String Soql = 'SELECT LastModifiedDate,Plaintiff_Full_Name__c,Plaintiff_Last_Name__c FROM Case limit 3';
List<sObject> L = Database.query(Soql);

String jsonResponse = Json.serialize(L);
String url = 'http://Localhost:1025/ErpApiService/api/PriceForCustomerB/';
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
system.debug('got request');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

req.setEndpoint(url);
system.debug('setendpoint');
//req.setMethod('GET');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setBody(jsonResponse);
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

Comment: your endpoint url is likely part of the problem here. This code is being run on _Salesforce's_ servers, not your local machine, so any url with "localhost" in it is incorrect. To make your callout, the service you're calling out to needs to be accessible from the public internet (you'll likely need to poke a hole in a firewall/port forward from your public IP to your local machine that is hosting the service you're trying to call).